# How to complete git submodule update --init --recursive offline?

Tags: git, github

The server I use cannot connect to `github`. I'm installing an emulator. The `git submodule update --init --recursive` command in the installed script cannot be completed. When executed,

> fatal: unable to access'https://github.com/ucb-bar/ariane-wrapper
> .git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: connection timeout
> fatal: Cannot clone'https://github.com/ucb-bar/ariane-wrapper.git' to submodule path'generators/ariane'

How to complete git submodule update --init --recursive offline?
I downloaded it offline, uploaded it to the server, and commented out this line of code. Is this okay? What else needs to be done?

Comment: Clearly it can't be done offline. Do it on a online machine and copy the whole thing into your work machine.

Comment: _"...commented out this line of code"_ - what line of code?

Comment: git submodule update --init --recursive

Comment: I think if you run the update command on your staging machine, then you know your sandbox is up to date before you copy it to the isolated server, so yes, leaving out that command on the isolated server should be the right solution for you.